# Math for Radar / Battlezone Type game

Tags: math, geometry

It pains me to say when I was younger I never paid attention as much as I should have in Math class... So, I'm asking the community at hand for some thoughts on where to start looking.

I've been thinking lately how some games like Battlezone, Robot Tank, etc were made back in the 80's. If I wanted to make a game like that, what Math would I need to implement the radar used in those games and how would I translate that into a first person view? Any examples out there that I can dissect?

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few general approaches one can take to the math in such games.

- One approach is to keep track of the positions of all objects, including the player, in a rectangular coordinate system, with an increasing Y always representing the same direction (e.g. "north").  For this approach to work well, there should be a limit to the space in which objects can travel.
- Another approach is to keep track of the positions of everything but the player in a fixed-direction coordinate system as above, but assume the player is always at 0,0; to move the player by a certain distance, shift the locations of all other objects by that distance.  Objects whose distance from the player gets too large should generally cease to exist, though in some cases having the coordinates "wrap" may be acceptable too (so if the player wanders far enough in a cardinal compass direction, objects will reappear).
- Yet another approach is to use a player-centered coordinate system but continously rotate things so that the increasing Y direction is always straight ahead of the player.  This approach simplifies drawing, but makes it much more expensive to rotate the player especially if one wants to avoid having other objects move around slightly.  On the other hand, this approach can work acceptably for some games where all the non-player objects are moving around enough that some stray motion caused by numerical shortcuts wouldn't be too noticeable.
- Finally, one could endeavor to store the position of everything but the player in polar coordinates.  This approach wouldn't have much to recommend it if one were trying to portray things accurately, but some games have used a very rough approximation of it with reasonable success.

On modern hardware, I would suggest one of the first two approaches.  The latter two were sometimes useful when writing games for 1980's game machines or computers, which had less than 1% of the RAM (sometimes less than 1/1,000,000 of the RAM--literally!) and ran at less than 1/1000 of the speed of today's machines, but are mentioned mainly for historical interest.

If your game keeps object positions in a positive-Y is north coordinate system, one can figure out where they should appear on screen by first computing the X and Y relative to the player's position (if coordinates aren't kept in that format, subtract player X and Y from the real position).  Then convert those coordinates to positive-Y-is-ahead coordinates by computing MX = X*sin(heading)+Y*cos(heading) and MY = Y*sin(heading)-X*cos(heading).  The screen coordinates for point at MX,MY,Z (with Z coordinate 0 and screen coordinate 0 at the horizon) will be SX = MX/MY and SY = Z/MY.

You may have to play around with scaling and units to make objects appear the proper size and proportion, and avoid drawing objects which get too close to the player (or worse, go behind), but the above formulae should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you would be trying to convert from a [cartesian coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) (i.e., x, y coordinates) to [polar coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) (i.e., an angle and a distance from the center of the "radar").  This is a relatively straightforward trigonometric transformation.